# Can't access to my data from a SWR fetch - React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Hello i try to build an app that fetch data from an API.
I use SWR Hooks to fetch data

```js
// libs/fetch.js
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch"

export default async function(...args) {
  const res = await fetch(...args)
  return res.json()
}
```

```js
// App.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import "./styles.css"
import useSWR from "swr"
import fetch from './libs/fetch'

export default function App() {
  const url = "https://data.grandpoitiers.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=mobilites-stationnement-des-parkings-en-temps-reel&facet=Places_restantes"
  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetch)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I cannot access the data value. when i try `data.records` it returns `Cannot read property 'records' of undefined`

I don't know what to do, i search but i don't found the answer.

Editor :
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/MattixNow/PoitiersParker/tree/80871ba94769346a7008312bdb6e4c1143e591a3

Can someone help me ? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the docs, you have to handle the error and loading cases

```
export default function App() {
    const url =
        "https://data.grandpoitiers.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=mobilites-stationnement-des-parkings-en-temps-reel&facet=Places_restantes"
    const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetch)

    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>

    return (
        <div className="App">

            {JSON.stringify(data.records)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: !data check is really important. In my case api fetch was taking some time so it was causing undefined error and page loading was stopped. But using this react rendered loading.... till data fetch was complete.

Comment: Same here. The check for !data got it worked here. Seems like it took some time, too. Thanks for the answer and the comment

Comment: This answer didn't solve the exact problem for me .

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've just added [default](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/error-handling#status-code-and-error-object) SWR fetcher function before calling useSWR:

```
  const fetcher = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);

    // If the status code is not in the range 200-299,
    // we still try to parse and throw it.
    if (!res.ok) {
      const error = new Error("An error occurred while fetching the data.");
      // Attach extra info to the error object.
      error.info = await res.json();
      error.status = res.status;
      throw error;
    }

    return res.json();
  };
```

I than used it:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetch)
```

And behold, `loading...`'s gonne and date is here :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case sometimes data were a string sometimes data were an object, i had to change my fetcher to async/await.

Curious thing when data were string it just were missing the closing '}'

```js
export const fetcher = async <T = any>(url: string) => {
  const { data } = await api.get<T>(url);
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Before fetch data from the server, JSON.stringify(data.records) were run first or concurrently. An error occurred because it was executed before fetching data from the server.

```
  <div className="App">

      {
        data&&

        JSON.stringify(data.records)
      }

  </div>
```